# Broadcast Receiver for cancel downloading in android

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I have built app which download file from link using DownloadManager and show progress wheel while downloading. Once downloading is completed I send broadcast receiver to change progress wheel to downloaded icon.

Now facing an issue that if I cancel the downloading from notification tray I don't get any broadcast for this so the progress wheel does not stop.

Can anyone have idea how can I get broadcast for cancel downloading?

Comment: do you have a "cancel" button in the notification tray?

Comment: @Lino I am using download manager for downloading. Cancel button added automatically in android nougat in notification tray.

Answer (score 1):

To get event of downloading process you need to register downloadManager to broadcast receiver.

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    mContext.registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
```

Here, Broadcast receiver is :

```
   private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkDownloadStatus(intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1));
    }
};
```

So when downloading cancels or successfully downloaded or any error, you will get status. Even you cancel from notification. You can check status by:

```
    private void checkDownloadStatus(long downloadReference) {
    DownloadManager.Query myDownloadQuery = new DownloadManager.Query();
    myDownloadQuery.setFilterById(downloadReference);
```

//Query the download manager about downloads that have been requested.
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(myDownloadQuery);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

```
        //column for status
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
        int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        //column for reason code if the download failed or paused
        int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
        int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);
        //get the download filename

        String statusText = "";
        String reasonText = "";

        switch (status) {
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED:
                statusText = "STATUS_FAILED";
                switch (reason) {
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_CANNOT_RESUME";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ALREADY_EXISTS";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_FILE_ERROR:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_FILE_ERROR";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_HTTP_DATA_ERROR";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_UNHANDLED_HTTP_CODE";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                        reasonText = "ERROR_UNKNOWN";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED:
                statusText = "STATUS_PAUSED";
                switch (reason) {
                    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI:
                        reasonText = "PAUSED_QUEUED_FOR_WIFI";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_UNKNOWN:
                        reasonText = "PAUSED_UNKNOWN";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK:
                        reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK";
                        break;
                    case DownloadManager.PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY:
                        reasonText = "PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING:
                statusText = "STATUS_PENDING";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING:
                statusText = "STATUS_RUNNING";
                break;
            case DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL:
                statusText = "STATUS_SUCCESSFUL";

                break;
        }

    }

}
```

On error, you can stop your progressbar.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I am sending a broadcast but it's not working.

Comment: Problem with this is the intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1) will always return -1 since it does not exist when cancel button is fixed. I have not figured it out how to receive which file that was hit cancel on yet...